# How to indent HTML tag content

Tags: html, indentation

Maybe this is a too basic question.

```
<p>A long text here A long text here A long text here A long text here A long text here A long text here A long text here A long text here </p>
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
<p>A long text here A long text here A long text here 
  A long text here ...
  ...
</p>
```

Also, help me tagging this question.

Comment: Possible in what sense?  I mean, you just did it in your question...

Comment: Are you talking about formatting for viewing in a browser for users? Or are you talking about formatting in code?

Comment: hmm, I asked a dumb thing, sorry. @Explosion Pills is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the paragraph tag removes leading white spaces and ignores enter breaks.

One way to achieve what you want would be to use the Preformatted tag `<pre>` which returns the result identical to it's base text (with spaces, breaks etc). Another way would be to try styling it with CSS *(width, text-indent, etc)* in the way it's best representative to the user.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers include some truth, here is a different approach using CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/p3pgz/

Simply include:

```
p {
   white-space: pre;
}
```

This ensures output of white space and line breaks as written in HTML editor. [White-Space property description at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the

```
<br/> tag within the <p> tag for getting the required indentation.. something like <p>A long text here A long text here A long text here <br/> A long text here A long text here A long text here </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `&nbsp;` a few times, or use CSS:

```
p {
    text-indent:-20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KCav/)